# How to Validate a String with Colon Restriction

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a boolean function to support double colons `::` only for a string. It should reject any string with non-consecutive colon or more than two consecutive colons. The appearance of double colons can be any number. I can write regex which supports double colons but I don't know how to reject so many combinations of non-consecutive and consecutivec colons. Any idea is appreciated!

Valid inputs: `Customer::Table`, `Customer::Table::Sub`

Invalid inputs: `Customer:Table`, `Customer::Table:Sub`, `Customer::::Table`

Comment: Can you give example of valid and invalid input please ?

Comment: @thibsc update the description with few examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one line option using `String#matches`:

```
String input = "Customer::Table::Sub";
if (input.matches("[^:]+(?:::[^:]+)*")) {
    System.out.println("MATCH");
}
```

### Demo

Here is an explanation of the regex used:

```
[^:]+          match one or more non colon characters
(?:            start non capturing group
    ::[^:]+    match :: again followed by one or more non :
)*             the group occurring zero or more times
```

Comment: Elegant! I tried few other combinations and they all worked. Can you add some explanation around ```(?:::[^:]+)``` ?

Comment: I have added an explanation to the regex.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder if we really need the non-capturing group? Seems the purpose of it is to parse the string but my function will be a boolean function.

Comment: @dashenswen You may remove the non capturing group, but leaving it in might boost performance slightly.

Comment: Can you shoot me a quick link with the explanation that why it might boost performance

Comment: Read: [What is a non-capturing group in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions)